# LibGdx java Preference confusion

Tags: java, libgdx, preferences

So im trying to figure out preferences for a game im creating, however im getting dumbfounded by it.

So my preferences file right now reads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="Level_Default">Default</entry>
</properties>
```

However for my code to get certain levels and what not looks like this.

```
        if (!(PreferenceManager.getPreferences("Zero").equals("Zero")))
        {
        game.batch.draw(levelOneButtonLocked, BUTTON_WIDTH * 2 / GravitySpikes.PPM,
                ROW_ONE_BUTTON_Y / GravitySpikes.PPM, BUTTON_WIDTH / GravitySpikes.PPM,
                BUTTON_HEIGHT / GravitySpikes.PPM);

        }
        else if (PreferenceManager.getPreferences("Zero").equals("Zero"))
        {
            if (Gdx.input.getX() / GravitySpikes.PPM < (levelOneX + BUTTON_WIDTH) / GravitySpikes.PPM
                    && Gdx.input.getX() / GravitySpikes.PPM > levelOneX / GravitySpikes.PPM
                    && (GravitySpikes.HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY()) / GravitySpikes.PPM < (ROW_ONE_BUTTON_Y + BUTTON_HEIGHT)
                            / GravitySpikes.PPM
                    && (GravitySpikes.HEIGHT - Gdx.input.getY()) / GravitySpikes.PPM > ROW_ONE_BUTTON_Y
                            / GravitySpikes.PPM) {
                game.batch.draw(levelOneButtonActive, BUTTON_WIDTH * 2 / GravitySpikes.PPM,
                        ROW_ONE_BUTTON_Y / GravitySpikes.PPM, BUTTON_WIDTH / GravitySpikes.PPM,
                        BUTTON_HEIGHT / GravitySpikes.PPM);

                if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                    game.setScreen(new LevelOneGameScreen(game));
                }
            } else {
                game.batch.draw(levelOneButtonInactive, BUTTON_WIDTH * 2 / GravitySpikes.PPM,
                        ROW_ONE_BUTTON_Y / GravitySpikes.PPM, BUTTON_WIDTH / GravitySpikes.PPM,
                        BUTTON_HEIGHT / GravitySpikes.PPM);
            }
        }
```

I'm not an expert at programming, just starting to use libgdx and what not, but the problem is why is the first if not working and the else if is executing when that entry isn't even in my preferences? I tried deleting the preference file and it still does the same thing even though that preference is not even there. I feel like i missed something very simple.

Also another note: Whenever i do beat my game and go to the next level it does add the entry normally.

Okay i solved my own problem, it had to do with my getPreferences.

before it was
return getPreferenceFile().getString("Level_" + level, level);

but i changed it to this and it seems to work fine now.
return getPreferenceFile().getString("Level_" + level);

Comment: are you sure that the .xml is the proper one?

Comment: yea im pretty sure @m.antkowicz

Comment: What type of object does `PreferenceManager.getPreferences()` return?

By the way, it's redundant to do `else if` with the exact opposite criteria of the `if` that precedes it. Just do `else`.

Comment: return getPreferenceFile().getString("Level_" + level, level); A String. and yeah im just testing things for now, not to worried about it but i see your point

Comment: I think i fixed it

Comment: I'm not sure your code above matches what you've been testing. If the file isn't there, wouldn't the line `return getPreferenceFile().getString("Level_" + level, level);` throw an NPE?

Comment: Idk im confused as you but my getpreferencefile() looks like this --- 
                                                                                                    if (levelPrefs == null)
   levelPrefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("UserLevelData.txt");
     
  
  return levelPrefs;